# Update 2 table with join clause

Tags: mysql

I try to update some field from 2 tables with join clause.
But every test is bad, mysql return error.

My query is:

```
    UPDATE `Table1` t1 , `Table2` t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table2` t3 ON t1.acIndex = t3.ecActe
SET t2.ecDate=DATE_SUB(t2.ecDate, INTERVAL 183 DAY), t1.acDateF=DATE_SUB(t1.acDateF, INTERVAL 183 DAY), t1.acDateDebut=DATE_SUB(t1.acDateDebut, INTERVAL 183 DAY) 
WHERE (t1.acTraitement='5861' AND t1.acDateDebut>'2012-12-07' )
```

So could you help me to found why query is bad?
Thanks

Comment: The actual error returned by MySQL conveys considerable information.  It probably tells you exactly what is wrong.  It would be helpful to include it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. Try this query -

```
UPDATE
  `Table1` t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table2` t2
  ON t1.acIndex = t2.ecActe
SET
  t2.ecDate = DATE_SUB(t2.ecDate, INTERVAL 183 DAY),
  t1.acDateF = DATE_SUB(t1.acDateF, INTERVAL 183 DAY),
  t1.acDateDebut = DATE_SUB(t1.acDateDebut, INTERVAL 183 DAY)
WHERE
  (t1.acTraitement = '5861' AND t1.acDateDebut > '2012-12-07')
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html):

> #### Join Processing Changes in MySQL 5.0.12
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - Previously, the comma operator (`,`) and `JOIN` both had the same precedence, so the join expression `t1, t2 JOIN t3` was interpreted as `((t1, t2) JOIN t3)`. Now `JOIN` has higher precedence, so the expression is interpreted as `(t1, (t2 JOIN t3))`. This change affects statements that use an `ON` clause, because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes interpretation of what those operands are.
>
>   Example:
>
>   ```
>   CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 INT, j1 INT);
>   CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 INT, j2 INT);
>   CREATE TABLE t3 (i3 INT, j3 INT);
>   INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1);
>   INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,1);
>   INSERT INTO t3 VALUES(1,1);
>   SELECT * FROM t1, t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   Previously, the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) was legal due to the implicit grouping of `t1,t2` as `(t1,t2)`. Now the `JOIN` takes precedence, so the operands for the `ON` clause are `t2` and `t3`. Because `t1.i1` is not a column in either of the operands, the result is an `Unknown column 't1.i1' in 'on clause'` error. To allow the join to be processed, group the first two tables explicitly with parentheses so that the operands for the `ON` clause are `(t1,t2)` and `t3`:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM (t1, t2) JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   Alternatively, avoid the use of the comma operator and use `JOIN` instead:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   This change also applies to statements that mix the comma operator with `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and `RIGHT JOIN`, all of which now have higher precedence than the comma operator.

Comment: Thanks your help. It help me to understand